# Avoiding code repetition in get/set functions for threadsafe struct member access

Tags: c, struct, pthreads

I'm refactoring an older C project with multiple files and threads. Currently, global state variables are written/read with no synchronization in many places, and are loosely associated via a variable naming convention. I would like to group related variables into globally shared structs, each containing a mutex for thread safety, something like this:

```c
// Struct that will contain data to be written/read across multiple threads
typedef struct {
    pthread_mutex_t Mutex;
    int Field1;
    float Field2;
} MyStruct;
```

I also want to put the mutex locking and error check inside of functions, like so:

```c
int SetField1(MyStruct *my_struct, int field_1) {

    int mutex_lock_error;

    mutex_lock_error = pthread_mutex_lock(&(my_struct->Mutex));
    if (!mutex_lock_error) {
        my_struct->Field1 = field_1;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(my_struct->Mutex));
    }

    return mutex_lock_error;
}

int GetField1(MyStruct *my_struct, int *field_1) {

    int mutex_lock_error;

    mutex_lock_error = pthread_mutex_lock(&(my_struct->Mutex));
    if (!mutex_lock_error) {
        *field_1 = my_struct->Field1;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(my_struct->Mutex));
    }

    return mutex_lock_error;
}
```

However, since not all of the struct members are the same type, and have different names, I need to do this as well:

```c
int SetField2(MyStruct *my_struct, float field_2) {

    int mutex_lock_error;

    mutex_lock_error = pthread_mutex_lock(&(my_struct->Mutex));
    if (!mutex_lock_error) {
        my_struct->Field2 = field_2;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(my_struct->Mutex));
    }

    return mutex_lock_error;
}

int GetField2(MyStruct *my_struct, float *field_2) {

    int mutex_lock_error;

    mutex_lock_error = pthread_mutex_lock(&(my_struct->Mutex));
    if (!mutex_lock_error) {
        *field_2 = my_struct->Field2;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(my_struct->Mutex));
    }

    return mutex_lock_error;
}
```

This is a lot of similar code, and this struct only has 2 different members. Is there a standard way of doing this that doesn't require separate get/set functions for each struct member?

### Possible solutions I have thought of

Pass in a second parameter of type MyStruct/*MyStruct (local to the caller) and copy the values to and from this, so only one get and one set function are needed. This seems like it will obfuscate the intent of the code, and also has the huge drawback of needing to read the state before each write so that the other fields are not affected.

Some horrible witchcraft with *void, sizeof, offsetof and passing number of bytes as an argument. I haven't tried implementing this yet, and probably won't, as it opens up far more (and worse) problems than it solves.

Note -the compiler is older (gcc 4.1.2) so I do not have access to _Generic. I am in the process of changing this, but cannot count on it happening any time soon.

Comment: You can probably write a macro to do this.

Comment: `opens up far more (and worse) problems than it solves` Exactly. You will spend days to optimize something you just do in seconds with ctrl+c+v and some type changing. Just write all accessor functions.

Comment: *"huge drawback of needing to read the state before each write so that the other fields are not affected."* In fact, that idea won't work at all, because the caller's local copy will be out-of-date as soon as the `get` function returns.

Comment: A possible solution is to write a code generator. The code generator is given the structure definition as input, and creates a .c file and a .h file containing all of the setters and getters.

Comment: All good points, thanks. Code generator + functions for each field is probably what I'll go with

Comment: This approach will work in some cases. In others it can lull you into believing that the thread synchronization issues are taken care of when that is not at all the reality. In some circumstances, what needs protection is not a simple single access, but an interaction that is composed of several related accesses. Be sure to check your use cases to be sure that your approach will cover your synchronization needs before you become too invested in a particular implementation.